# Spring MVC @RequestMapping to return nothing, simply close

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm working on a JSP that gathers info and after it's Submitted the page closes and then goes to a Confirmation page. I don't want the Confirmation page. After clicking Submit on the JSP, I simply want the window to close. The Return value on the Controller needs a value. What can I put in there that will allow it to simply end? 
This is my Controller:

```
@Controller
//@SessionAttributes({"resultBoard", "filterBoard"})
public class NewEmployeeController {

    NewEmployeeService newEmpService;

    @Autowired
    public NewEmployeeController(NewEmployeeService service){
        this.newEmpService = service;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "NewEmpInput", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String promptEmployee(Model model)
    {
        //JSP can only reference 1 object, but need to reference many objects. So I put many classes inside EmployeeFormWrapper wrapper class.
        model.addAttribute("myForm", new EmployeeFormWrapper());
        return "NewEmpInput";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "NewEmpInput", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String newEmployee(@ModelAttribute("myForm") EmployeeFormWrapper myForm)
    {

        NewEmployeeVM employee = myForm.getEmployee();
        ClientVM client = myForm.getClient();
        ProjectVM project = myForm.getProject();
        System.out.println("Employee = " + employee.getFirstName() + " " + employee.getLastName());
        System.out.println("Client = " + client.getText());
        System.out.println("Project = " + project.getText());

        newEmpService.saveNewEmployee(employee);

        return "ConfirmNewEmp";
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe set the Controller @RequestMapping method to void return value and then put some javascript in the JSP for window.close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed method in java controller to return void. I added this script to my jsp:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function closeWindow() {
        window.close();
    }
</script>
```

and updated the first line of my form in my jsp to this:

```
<form:form commandName="employee" modelAttribute="employee" onsubmit="closeWindow()">
```

my submit button in jsp stays the same:

```
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</p>
```

and now it works. Thanks.